# How to transfer data from .map to function from href element with onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-redux

I'm trying to move one element from .map to onClick function so that I can pass it to redux but I'm not sure how to proceed. This is my code

```
const Lists = lists.map((list, index) =>
    <li key={index}> {list.name} <a href="#" onClick={this.listInfo.bind(this)}>Learn More</a> </li> );
```

this is the function

```
listInfo(event){
  event.preventDefault();
  var el = list.name //this is where I want to save that value;
  console.log(el)
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this....

```
const Lists = lists.map((list, index) =>
<li key={index}> {list.name} <a href="#" onClick={(e) => this.listInfo(e, list.name)}>Learn More</a> </li> );
```

And change your function to this...

```
listInfo(event, listName){
//.....
console.log(listName);
}
```

Comment: Please **explain** what you changed and *why* (what is the problem and how does your solution solve it?) *"Try this..."* is not a useful statement.